# Regular Expression - rename pictures

Tags: regex, rename, pictures

THE PROBLEM:

1000's pictures with --0.jpg at the end (double hyphen)
Example: `toni-like-to-play-football--0.jpg`

And I want change the `--0.jpg` to `-0.jpg`

It would be easy with my tool (Bulk Rename Utility) to replace all with the normal replacement function: replace `--0.jpg` with `-0.jpg`

But unfortunately it is a whole picture set that is continuous until -09
Example:

```
toni-like-to-play-football--0.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football--1.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football--2.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football--3.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football--4.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football--5.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football--6.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football--7.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football--8.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football--9.jpg
```

Now i looking for a RegEx which rename `--0.jpg --1.jpg --2.jpg  ... --9.jpg` 
to `-0.jpg -1.jpg -2.jpg  ... -9.jpg`

At the end there should be only - (one hyphen) and the number.

This would be the result:

```
toni-like-to-play-football-0.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football-1.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football-2.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football-3.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football-4.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football-5.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football-6.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football-7.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football-8.jpg
toni-like-to-play-football-9.jpg
```

Hope someone have time to call me the RegEx for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you've got filenames with `--` in the middle of them, the easiest way would be:

Search:   `--` 
Replace: `-`

If you do have filenames like that then use the following regexp:

Search:  `\-\-(\d)`
Replace: `\-\1`

If your number goes above 9 then use this instead:

Search:  `\-\-(\d+)`
Replace: `\-\1`.

Comment: Hi David, thanks a lot i will test is right now (but it could take some hours - because i have to edit a lot of pictures). And than i will write if that is the solution. THANKS, THANKS and THANKS :)